# Check current back pressure level in Node.js stream

Tags: node.js, stream, backpressure

Is there a way in Node.js to check the back pressure state of a Stream? For example to compare it to the high water mark.

My use case is inside a unit tests, I'd like to make sure a transform stream plugin is draining the pipe and doesn't build up back pressure on the output stream.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @JamesTalmage unfortunately not :(